# http.client.HTTPSConnection request errors can't be catch

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a GET request surrounded by try\catch in case hostname can't be DNS queried or network is failing.

Trying to surround with try\catch seems to not working and an error is raised.

```py
import http.client

try:
   conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("non.existent.url")
   conn.request("GET", "/")
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

I'm expecting the exception to be caught and printed out but instead, the code will exit with the error:

```
Exception has occurred: gaierror
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Can you show the error you see? I see no issue here, it prints out the exceptions error message. The exception is caught.

Comment: No the debugger stop the program with the error. The error isn't catched and can't be managed

Comment: Which OS? I am on ubuntu I get `[Errno -2] Name or service not known` and it is printed because the exception is caught.

Comment: Win10. I think that the error number is OS-related but still no catch.

Comment: I'm trying on a Debian. Reporting ASAP

Comment: I've found out the issue. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working as intended even on Win10. The issue was that VSCode Debugger has Breakpoint: Raised Error checked. This makes VSCode breakpoint a caught error.